# KDE Auto Logout After Inactivity

Tags: kubuntu, logout, plasma-5, kde5

How do I set KDE to automatically log out users after a period of inactivity?

Reason: Shared server with many users. Some people leave themselves logged in to KDE for many days.

Preferably want a solution that will apply to all users on an ubuntu server. Alternatively, this could be solved by killing a specific user process that has been inactive for X minutes.

Users log in to KDE with x2go via ssh.

Answer (score 1):

There is a package in the repositories which should do this:

> AUTOLOG(8)                  System Manager's Manual
> AUTOLOG(8)
>
> NAME
> autolog - Log out idle users
>
> SYNOPSIS
> autolog [ options ]
>
> DESCRIPTION
> The program reads the utmp file, entry by entry.  The username for each
> 'user process' is compared to the entries  in  the  configuration  file
> (see  autolog.conf(5)  ).   The first entry to match both the name, the
> group, and the tty line of the process will be used to conduct the  au‐
> tomatic logout.

You can install this with `sudo apt install autolog`, it is in the universe repository

Comment: How would I configure this to logout an idle KDE user?

Comment: You would need to create a suitable configuration file for the program - there's little online about it, but you can wrk through the manpages. [http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man5/autolog.conf.5.html](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man5/autolog.conf.5.html)

Comment: @Bastion Also found a KDE specific example ...  [https://superuser.com/questions/688720/how-do-i-auto-log-off-users-from-ubuntu](https://superuser.com/questions/688720/how-do-i-auto-log-off-users-from-ubuntu)